# make swf read its own name

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating an app using flash cc. In the app I need to load external swf files which are bunch of games. I need swf files to read its own name. I used

`var swfName:String = decodeURIComponent(this.loaderInfo.url.split("/").pop())` code to read its name. It works. But the problem I had with my app was the size. So I had to exclude external `swf` file from apk and load it from sd card. The problem with that was sandbox error. So I used `byteArray` and `loaderContext` to bypass the sandbox error. It work great except now the swf files is not reading its own file name but instead it is reading app's name. Is there anyway that I can make swf files read its own name while loading it using `byteArray` ? Any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Loader object is a parent to document root of loaded content. Pass what you want in the Loader.name property:

```
var aLoader:Loader;
var aSource:ByteArray;

aLoader = new Loader();
aLoader.name = "foo.swf";
aLoader.loadBytes(aSource);
```

Then in the document root of external SWF (class or frame, irrelevant):

```
trace(parent);     // [object Loader]
trace(parent.name) // foo.swf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need swf file to read its own name for cross checking and some security purpose. Can't it read its own file name?

Comment: Bypassing the security **is** why are you doing it this way. There's no file name embedded into content. You can load from somewhere it or you can write it byte by byte into your ByteArray in the runtime, it's all the same.

Comment: You can investigate if you can load your files from File.applicationStorageDirectory place to avoid that sandbox error (I cannot guarantee this will work), then you can copy your files there from external folder where you keep them.

Comment: File.applicationStorageDirectory won't avoid sandbox error.

Comment: Well, then you'll probably have to re-organize your packages so that all SWFs with script are embedded in APK and all the heavy graphics you have out there (what do you pack there anyway that heavy?) is loaded from outside location.

Comment: its a game file and there's hundreds of them. I guess I've to write the file name in a string variable in every files. It would have been easier if the swf file could read its name on its own. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you please explain the point? What is that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I've created an app which loads external swfs which are small games. At first I include all files with the apk. But the problem with that was the size of the apk. In each swf files there's some code for security purpose. I know its not enough but just to make it difficult so that swf files won't run own it's without apk file. One of them is to read swf file its own file name which was possible when I include the swf files with apk. But now I'm loading external files using byte array to avoid sandbox errors, it can't read its names with the same code that used to work.

Comment: Hmmmm, basically, if I copy these files without changing their names they will still work for me. How that is a **security** ?

Comment: it wont work own its own. You still need apk to run it.

Comment: Then why bother with the names at all?

Comment: I need the name to cross check if the correct file is loaded.